# Heroku Invalid DATABASE_URL when pushing - Heroku bug, fixed now

Tags: activerecord, heroku, sinatra

Edits:

This was a temporary bug with Heroku which they have fixed.

---

My push / deploy to heroku is failing when it was working last week. It's a sinatra app using activerecord on the cedar stack.

I was able to get my app deployed and running several times in Heroku. I'm using postgres and the cedar stack.

I have made one whitespace change to app.rb and pushed and the push was not accepted.

The app is currently actually working on the server with the code from last week. It is using the database, so it can see it.

Heroku info and heroku config lists the DATABASE_URL correctly.

I have created a new database, and promoted that but it didn't help (the running instance used the new database okay).

I created a new dyno running on cedar stack, set up a new db and provisioned it also but was unable to push the code to it with the same error.

The following is the error message: 
In this case I'm trying to use the latest version of sinatra activerecord to see if there was a bug (it didn't help)

```
git push heroku heroku_bug_before:master
Counting objects: 20, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
Writing objects: 100% (14/14), 1.60 KiB, done.
Total 14 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby/Rack app detected
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.2
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Using i18n (0.6.1)
       Using multi_json (1.7.7)
       Using activesupport (3.2.13)
       Using builder (3.0.4)
       Using activemodel (3.2.13)
       Using arel (3.0.2)
       Using tzinfo (0.3.37)
       Using activerecord (3.2.13)
       Using backports (3.3.3)
       Using bond (0.4.3)
       Using eventmachine (1.0.3)
       Using kgio (2.8.0)
       Using libxml-ruby (2.6.0)
       Using mime-types (1.23)
       Using oj (2.1.4)
       Using pg (0.15.1)
       Using r18n-core (1.1.5)
       Using rack (1.5.2)
       Using rack-protection (1.5.0)
       Using rack-test (0.6.2)
       Using raindrops (0.11.0)
       Using rest-client (1.6.7)
       Using ripl (0.7.0)
       Using ripl-multi_line (0.3.1)
       Using ripl-rack (0.2.0)
       Using tilt (1.4.1)
       Using sinatra (1.3.2)
       Installing sinatra-activerecord (1.2.3)
       Using sinatra-contrib (1.3.2)
       Using sinatra-flash (0.3.0)
       Using sinatra-r18n (1.1.5)
       Using tux (0.3.0)
       Using unicorn (4.6.3)
       Using bundler (1.3.2)
       Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
       Removing sinatra-activerecord (1.2.2)
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
 !
 !     rake aborted!
 !     Invalid DATABASE_URL
 !     (erb):9:in `rescue in <main>'
 !     (erb):6:in `<main>'
 !     /tmp/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb:753:in `eval'
 !     /tmp/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb:753:in `result'
 !     /tmp/build_2b0q7ep6511dz/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-activerecord-1.2.3/lib/sinatra/activerecord.rb:39:in `database_file='
 !     /tmp/build_2b0q7ep6511dz/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:983:in `set'
 !     /tmp/build_2b0q7ep6511dz/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-activerecord-1.2.3/lib/sinatra/activerecord.rb:50:in `registered'
 !     /tmp/build_2b0q7ep6511dz/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1262:in `block in register'
 !     /tmp/build_2b0q7ep6511dz/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1260:in `each'
 !     /tmp/build_2b0q7ep6511dz/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1260:in `register'
 !     /tmp/build_2b0q7ep6511dz/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1590:in `register'
 !     /tmp/build_2b0q7ep6511dz/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1630:in `register'
 !     /tmp/build_2b0q7ep6511dz/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-activerecord-1.2.3/lib/sinatra/activerecord.rb:76:in `<module:Sinatra>'
 !     /tmp/build_2b0q7ep6511dz/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-activerecord-1.2.3/lib/sinatra/activerecord.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
 !     /tmp/build_2b0q7ep6511dz/app.rb:2:in `require'
 !     /tmp/build_2b0q7ep6511dz/app.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
 !     /tmp/build_2b0q7ep6511dz/Rakefile:1:in `require'
 !     /tmp/build_2b0q7ep6511dz/Rakefile:1:in `<top (required)>'
 !     /tmp/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `load'
 !     /tmp/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `raw_load_rakefile'
 !     /tmp/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2007:in `block in load_rakefile'
 !     /tmp/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
 !     /tmp/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2006:in `load_rakefile'
 !     (eval):1:in `block in standard_rake_options'
 !     /tmp/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2213:in `eval'
 !     /tmp/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2213:in `block in standard_rake_options'
 !     /tmp/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1308:in `call'
 !     /tmp/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1308:in `block in parse_in_order'
 !     /tmp/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1264:in `catch'
 !     /tmp/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1264:in `parse_in_order'
 !     /tmp/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1258:in `order!'
 !     /tmp/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1349:in `permute!'
 !     /tmp/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1370:in `parse!'
 !     /tmp/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2303:in `handle_options'
 !     /tmp/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1999:in `block in init'
 !     /tmp/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
 !     /tmp/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1997:in `init'
 !     /tmp/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1990:in `run'
 !     /tmp/ruby-1.9.2/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'
 !     (in /tmp/build_2b0q7ep6511dz)
 !
sh: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/Rack app
```

heroku config (you can see the extra db I added, and promoted)

```
=== visualtags Config Vars
DATABASE_URL:                 postgres://changed1:changed@ec2-54-217-215-81.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/changed1
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COBALT_URL: postgres://changed2:changed@ec2-54-217-215-81.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/changed2
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CYAN_URL:   postgres://changed3:changed@ec2-54-217-215-96.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/changed3
```

heroku pg:info

```
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COBALT_URL (DATABASE_URL)
Plan:        Dev
Status:      available
Connections: 4
PG Version:  9.2.4
Created:     2013-07-23 17:49 UTC
Data Size:   6.4 MB
Tables:      2
Rows:        4/10000 (In compliance) - refreshing
Fork/Follow: Unsupported
Region:      Europe
```

heroku info

```
=== herokuapp
Addons:        heroku-postgresql:dev
               heroku-postgresql:dev

Git URL:       xxx
Owner Email:   mine@example.com
Region:        eu
Repo Size:     8M
Slug Size:     17M
Stack:         cedar
Tier:          Legacy
Web URL:       http://xxx.herokuapp.com/
```

I've spent hours on this - it was working last week, but now it no longer works. I'm using Unicorn and ActiveRecord and following the advice in the docs for this also...

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Same issue here with Padrino/Datamapper and an Heroku Postgre Basic plan, I haven't been able to deploy since this morning.

The DATABASE_URL config var seem to be correctly set when I run 'heroku config' and I can access it from the Padrino console with ENV['DATABASE_URL'] so not sure what's causing the problem.

This guy [configuring heroku database connection in padrino - DATABASE_URL fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218592/configuring-heroku-database-connection-in-padrino-database-url-fails) has been able to use HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_color_URL directly and it fixed it but not for my app.

Looks like a problem with Heroku deploy script, best thing to do is to raise a ticket with them https://help.heroku.com/tickets/new?query=postgre

(Sorry that's more a comment than an actual answer, apparently I don't have enough rep for commenting)

---

EDIT: Heroku replied to my ticket saying the problem was fixed and I can deploy my apps successfully again.

Comment: Thanks! It does indeed seem to have been an error with Heroku themselves, and they have fixed it now. It has been able to push successfully.

Comment: Hey guys, it seems it appeared once again, Today 9 of November 2013, i'm trying to deploy a simple app on heroku it gets deploy but when i visit URL in browser it throws "500 Internal server Error" with "invalid DATABASE_URL", Any thoughts Thanks.